# Why does this order by then group by not work?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have MySQL tables like:

```
Users (id)
Posts (id, user_id, created)
```

Then let's say I want to try to get the most recent post for each user

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY created DESC) AS b GROUP BY user_id
```

It is not correctly returning the most recent post, however, it does when not grouping. What is the proper way to perform such a query?

Comment: your sub query is redundant. Why not select from posts directly?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM posts GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY created DESC` produces improper results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be overthinking it - think eaiser.

Assuming that your post IDs are sequential, then the largest ID corresponds to the latest post - and you can get your data like this:

```
select user_id, id, created from Posts where id in
(select max(id) from posts group by user_id)
```